# Unable to send outbound requests from .NET Core Docker container

Tags: docker, .net-core

I've a .NET Core Docker container which is unable to send requests to the outside world. I can't curl or ping anything, including a dns record like 8.8.8.8. A MongoDB container however is able to ping and curl to the outside world.

I've tried several images:

- microsoft/dotnet:2.0-runtime
- microsoft/aspnetcore

Incoming connections to the container works fine.

Docker is running on a ubuntu machine. I'm using Docker Swarm to manage my containers.

Error:

```
PING 109.236.87.141 (109.236.87.141): 56 data bytes
ping: sending packet: Network is unreachable
```

The difference between the network configuration between the .NET Core container and Mongo is the Core container doesn't include a "ingress" network.

Comment: Are you getting an error message? That's an important detail to include.

Comment: @mason I've added the error.

Answer (score 0):

After investigating some other docker containers I noticed some of them had a bridge network attached to them. After adding this network the container was able to connect to the outside world.